# How to find which field has been updated in the form using PHP and MYSQLi

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

I have a form with few input fields and a update option ,suppose if i have 10 fields and i update only first two fields and not the rest who can i display a message that only the first to field  A and B are updated using PHP and Mysqli

[image]

in the screenshot if i update the value of bill id and origin i should display message out in some other page that says that bill id and origin has been updated with "xyz " value

Comment: Share your try at least . This can be done by multiple ways.

Comment: I havent tried as such because i have no idea on it .Can you share your ideas.Can it be run through some mysli query that i will be able to get the field names listed

Answer (score 0):

One way is to fetch fields with real and old name i.e.

```
 Select name,name as old_name from table
```

In html

```
 <input type="text" name="name" value="name from db"> 
 <input type="hidden" name="old_name" value="old_name from db">
```

After submit form you can check it by.

And check after post.

```
 If(post['name']==post['old_name'])
```

Something like this.

Another way is from js by checking onchange event

Comment: Thanks .the real and old name seems to be a good solution but i have around 40 fields .it would be nice if i get a better solution

Comment: Another way is from js but it should be initiate by you at least. You earlier said that you have only 10 fields.

Answer (score -1):

well it'll be something like this ..

html:

```
    <html>
    <body>
//action is defining the php file's name which the form will be sent to ;
//method is defining the method which the form will be sent with

    <form action="updateCheck.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="input-filed-1"/>
    <input type="text" name="input-filed-2"/>
    <input type="text" name="input-filed-3"/>
    <input type="text" name="input-filed-4"/>
    <input type"text" name="input-filed-5"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit/>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

create a file named updateCheck.php in the same directory and enter the  following code

```
     <?php $updateMessage = "you have updated the following fields";
        for($x = 0 ; $x<=5 ; $x++)
        {
// trim for erasing the whitespaces 
// that if clause checks if there was data entered in the update input fields
        if(isset($_POST["input-field-".$x]) && trim($_POST["input-field-".$x]))
        {
        $updateMessage.= "input-field-".$x ;
        }
        }
      echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('".$updateMessage."')</script>"
    ?>
```

I haven't tested the code .. but study it carefully and you'll see how it's done